# Pandas: Elementwise multiplication of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication, dataframe

I know how to do element by element multiplication between two Pandas dataframes. However, things get more complicated when the dimensions of the two dataframes are not compatible. For instance below `df * df2` is straightforward, but `df * df3` is a problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1.0] * 5, 
                   'col2' : [2.0] * 5, 
                   'col3' : [3.0] * 5 }, index = range(1,6),)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [10.0] * 5, 
                    'col2' : [100.0] * 5, 
                    'col3' : [1000.0] * 5 }, index = range(1,6),)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [0.1] * 5}, index = range(1,6),)

df.mul(df2, 1) # element by element multiplication no problems

df.mul(df3, 1) # df(row*col) is not equal to df3(row*col)
   col1  col2  col3
1   0.1   NaN   NaN
2   0.1   NaN   NaN
3   0.1   NaN   NaN
4   0.1   NaN   NaN
5   0.1   NaN   NaN
```

In the above situation, **how can I multiply every column of df with df3.col1**?

**My attempt:** I tried to replicate `df3.col1`  `len(df.columns.values)` times to get a dataframe that is of the same dimension as `df`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([df3.col1 for n in range(len(df.columns.values)) ])
df3
        1    2    3    4    5
col1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
col1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
col1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

But this creates a dataframe of dimensions 3 * 5, whereas I am after 5*3. I know I can take the transpose with `df3.T()` to get what I need but I think this is not that the fastest way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to multiply multiple columns by a column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702760/how-to-multiply-multiple-columns-by-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: The answer in there ^ is much better.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
In [161]: pd.DataFrame(df.values*df2.values, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
Out[161]: 
   col1  col2  col3
1    10   200  3000
2    10   200  3000
3    10   200  3000
4    10   200  3000
5    10   200  3000
```

Comment: Thank you unutbu. `pd.DataFrame(df.values*df3.values, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)` preserves the index as well, right?

Answer (score 22):

A simpler way to do this is just to multiply the dataframe whose colnames you want to keep with the values (i.e. numpy array) of the other, like so:

```
In [63]: df * df2.values
Out[63]: 
   col1  col2  col3
1    10   200  3000
2    10   200  3000
3    10   200  3000
4    10   200  3000
5    10   200  3000
```

This way you do not have to write all that new dataframe boilerplate.

Answer (score 5):

To utilize Pandas broadcasting properties, you can use [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.multiply.html).

```
df.multiply(df3['col1'], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
mul = df.mul(df3.c, axis=0)
```

Or, when you want to subtract (divide) instead:

```
sub = df.sub(df3.c, axis=0)
div = df.div(df3.c, axis=0)
```

Works also with a `nan` in df (e.g. if you apply this to the df: `df.iloc[0]['col2'] = np.nan)`

Comment: This doesn't work. If you meant `df.mul(df3.col1, axis=0)`, please rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is create list of columns and join them:

```
cols = [pd.DataFrame(df[col] * df3.col1, columns=[col]) for col in df]
mul = cols[0].join(cols[1:])
```