# how to multiply multiple columns by a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have:

```
df[['income_1', 'income_2']] * df['mtaz_proportion']
```

return those columns multiplied by `df['mtaz_proportion']`

so that I can set

```
df[['mtaz_income_1', 'mtaz_income_2']] = 
df[['income_1', 'income_2']] * df['mtaz_proportion']
```

but instead I get:

```
income_1    income_2    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
```

ect...

what simple thing am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

use `multiply` method and set `axis="index"`:

```
df[["A", "B"]].multiply(df["C"], axis="index")
```

Comment: Just a caveat: `df["C"]` may not behave as expected if passed as a DataFrame like `df[["C"]]`

Comment: The code works but the df doesn't hold it. (-> print(df) just gives the original df afterwards)

Instead do: df[["A", "B"]] = df[["A", "B"]].multiply(df["C"], axis="index") and then columns A and B in the df hold the changes

Comment: Do not know, but somehow all the row-columns become NaN after multiplication.

Comment: @EMT It happened to me as well but the issue got resolved by using `axis='index'`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of writing the answer of HYRY:

```
df.loc[:,['A', 'B']] = df.loc[:,['A', 'B']].multiply(df.loc[:, 'C'], axis="index")
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert both factors to *numpy* arrays using [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
df.loc[:, ['D', 'E']] = df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy() * df[['C']].to_numpy()
```