# Weights for histogram in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe (call it data) with categorical and continuous values that look like this:

```
INDEX  AGE  SEX  INCOME  COUNTRY  INSTANCE_WEIGHT
1      25   M    30000   USA      120
2      53   F    42000   FR       95
3      37   F    22000   USA      140
4      18   M    0       FR       110
.
.
.
15000  29  F     39000   USA      200
```

The instance weight indicates the number of people in the population that each record represents due to stratified sampling.

What I would like to do is plotting the distribution of each of the variable into an histogram. The problem is that I can't just plot an histogram of this current dataframe since it's not representative of the real distribution. To be representative, I have to multiply each row by its intance_weight before plotting it. The problem sounds easy but I can't find a good way of doing that.

A solution would be to duplicate each row `instance_weight` times but the real dataframe is 300k rows and `instance_weight`is around 1000.

This is the code I have for now to plot an histogram of each of the column.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,70))
cols = 4
rows = ceil(float(data.shape[1]) / cols)
for i, column in enumerate(data.drop(["instance_weight","index"], axis=1).columns):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, i + 1)
    ax.set_title(column)
    # Check if data categorical or not
    if data.dtypes[column] == np.object:
        data[column].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", axes=ax,
                                         alpha=0.8, color=sns.color_palette(n_colors=1))
    else:
        data[column].hist(axes=ax, alpha=0.8)
        plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1, wspace=0.2)
```

How to consider the weight now?

Comment: What do you want on the x and y axis?

Comment: You could multiply the numeric columns [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22702814/1292641), but that won't help with the non-numeric ones...

Answer (score 19):

You should use the 'weights' argument of the [matplotlib 'hist' function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), which is also available through the [pandas 'plot' function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

In your example, to plot the distribution of the variable 'AGE' weighted on the variable 'INSTANCE_WEIGHT', you should do:

```
df["AGE"].plot(kind="hist", weights=df["INSTANCE_WEIGHT"])
```