# Function in Pandas for reshape

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a dataset which as the following

```
customer    products    Sales
1           a           10
1           a           10
2           b           20
3           c           30
```

How can I reshape and to do that in python and pandas? I've tried with the pivot tools but since I have duplicated CUSTOMER ID it's not working...

```
Products                
customerID  a   b   c   
1           10          
1           10          
2              20       
3                   30  



{' update': {209: 'Originator',
 211: 'Originator', 
212: 'Originator',
 213: 'Originator',
 214: 'Originator'}, 
'CUSTOMER ID': {209: 1000368,
 211: 1000368, 212: 1000968, 213: 1000968, 214: 1000968},
 'NET SALES VALUE SANOFI':{209: 426881.0,
 211: 332103.0, 212: 882666.0, 213: 882666.0, 214: 294222.0},
 'PRODUCT FAMILY': {209: 'APROVEL',
 211: 'APROVEL', 212: 'APROVEL', 213: 'APROVEL', 214: 'APROVEL'}, 
'CHANNEL DEFINITION':
 {209: 'PHARMACY', 211: 'PHARMACY', 212: 'PHARMACY', 213: 'PHARMACY', 214: 'PHARMACY'}, 
'index': {209: 209, 211: 211, 212: 212, 213: 213, 214: 214}


CUSTOMER ID 1228675 non-null int64 
DISTRIBUTOR ID 1228675 non-null float64 
PRODUCT FAMILY 1228675 non-null 
object GROSS SALES QUANTITY 1228675 
non-null int64 GROSS SALES VALUE 1228675 
non-null int64 NET SALES VALUE 1228675 
non-null int64 DISCOUNT VALUES 1228675 
non-null int64 CHANNEL DEFINITION 1228675 non-null object
```

what i tried also : `ONLY_PHARMA.pivot_table(values = "NET SALES VALUE ", index = ["CUSTOMER ID"], columns = "PRODUCT FAMILY").reset_index()`

what im getting now a mix of float and Int....?? Why?

```
ID        A           B          C
1000167  NaN   2.380122e+05      244767.466667

or im having : 

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

OR I've done which also return me floats and int:

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(ONLY_PHARMA.reset_index(), index=['CUSTOMER ID'],
                              columns='PRODUCT FAMILY', values='NET SALES VALUE' , fill_value='') \
               .reset_index()
```

Comment: What code are you using? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry its my first post here. Im using Python and pandas. The pivot table fonction can't work on duplicates ID.

Comment: @SIMON_py Share your dataframe here with df.head().to_dict() seeing you got problem running functions that work for us.

Comment: You can find the dataframe up there

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
g = df.groupby(['customer', 'products']).cumcount()
df = (
      df.set_index([g, 'customer', 'products'])['Sales']
       .unstack().sort_index(level=1)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
      )
print (df)
products     a     b     c
customer                  
1         10.0   NaN   NaN
1         10.0   NaN   NaN
2          NaN  20.0   NaN
3          NaN   NaN  30.0
```

Notice:

If duplicated values, maybe need aggregation, check [how to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Something like: `df.customer.to_frame(name='customer_id').join(df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales')).fillna('').set_index('customer_id')` might do it

Comment: Key point is to start with `df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales')` I think... Heck - even `df.join(df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales'))` might do...

Comment: Hi John thanks for your help ! `df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales') and df.join(df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales') `are not working.... About this one : `df.customer.to_frame(name='customer_id').join(df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales')).fillna('').set_index('customer_id')`... i dont understand the df.customer at the beginning?

Comment: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 1000368 to 1000968
Data columns (total 1 columns):
APROVEL    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 80.0 bytes` Only returns me one product..?

Comment: @SIMON_py - I see your last edit and I am confused what is expected output. Can you add it to question? Or wht is problem? can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael IF i use your

Comment: @jezrael it shows the ids but only one product for some reason... I need to see the values for all the products... Let me explain... Mydataset: I have a columns of ID, one of total sales (42.32), one of the type of product (a,b,c)... Im wondering if the format of my data is causing me problems also? see my edits...

Comment: @SIMON_py - Your columns are `['Ambar update', 'CUSTOMER ID', 'NET SALES VALUE SANOFI', 'PRODUCT FAMILY', 'SANOFI CHANNEL DEFINITION', 'index']`. What is column `product` ?

Comment: @jezrael Also i dont want to group by the same ID to sum... If im grouping my values and doing on pivot its working properly.. But for some reasons it seems that the duplicate ID is the problem. Its product family

Comment: @SIMON_py - thanks. I think reason why you get only one columns is clear - in column `PRODUCT FAMILY` is always only same value `APROVEL`. so `APROVEL` create new column in new DataFrame. What is `print (df['PRODUCT FAMILY'].eq('APROVEL').sum())` of original `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Not sure to understand.. I dont want to sum or mean my products... I want all duplicates ID on a seperate line...

Comment: @jezrael i want to do exactly this https://codedump.io/share/geAjSS6EcG2l/1/pandas-transposing-one-column-in-a-multiple-column-df . But i dont want to average or count. I want to keep all the rows of my dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Here's fairly straight-forward way assuming you have a unique index, given your input of:

```
   customer products  Sales
0         1        a     10
1         1        a     10
2         2        b     20
3         3        c     30
```

Pivot it to columnise the products and rejoin to just the customer column on the original frame, eg:

```
new_df = df[['customer']].join(df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales'))
```

This'll give you:

```
   customer     a     b     c
0         1  10.0   NaN   NaN
1         1  10.0   NaN   NaN
2         2   NaN  20.0   NaN
3         3   NaN   NaN  30.0
```

Then sort out your indexing / filling blank values.

Comment: Nice1! A small modification suggestion: output of `df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales').set_index(df['customer'])` ressembles more what OP wanted.

Comment: @AntonvBR yeah... wasn't *quite* sure exactly what the output was supposed to be - I'm guessing the OP does so they can just index appropriately at the relevant stage...

Comment: For some reason in using this and `df.pivot(columns='products', values='Sales').set_index(df['customer'])` and Im getting only one column of one products... i should get in columns all my 50 products...

Answer (score 1):

Another method using [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

```
pd.concat([df, df.products.str.get_dummies().multiply(df["Sales"], axis="index")], 
          axis=1)


   customer products    Sales   a   b   c
0   1       a           10      10  0   0
1   1       a           10      10  0   0
2   2       b           20      0   20  0
3   3       c           30      0   0   30
```

`df.products.str.get_dummies()` creates dummy variables as follows

```
    a   b   c
0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0
3   0   0   1
```

We then need to multiply this dummy variable table with `df["Sales"]`. This is achieved by `df.products.str.get_dummies().multiply(df["Sales"], axis="index")` (See reference for more information.)

```
    a   b   c
0   10  0   0
1   10  0   0
2   0   20  0
3   0   0   30
```

Reference

[how to multiply multiple columns by a column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702760/how-to-multiply-multiple-columns-by-a-column-in-pandas)

Note: to replace `0` with `np.nan`, you need to add `.replace(0, np.nan)` like

`pd.concat([df, df.products.str.get_dummies().replace(0, np.nan).mul(df["Sales"], axis="index")], axis=1)`

Comment: Im having invalid syntax `pd.concat([df, df.products` , Im also already in a pandas dataframe

Comment: @SIMON_py can you post your whole line code? I cannot see where it went wrong.

Comment: Im trying also : `pvt = pd.pivot_table(ONLY_PHARMA.reset_index(), index=['index2'],
                              columns='PRODUCT FAMILY', values='NET SALES VALUE SANOFI', fill_value='') \
               .reset_index()` which returns in rows int and float for some reasons... I've create a new index in my dataframe but seems pandas dont see this unique Index for each rows

Comment: Sorry, my answer does not involve `pivot`... @SIMON_py

Comment: `pd.concat([df, df.PRODUCT FAMILY.str.get_dummies().multiply(df["NET SALES VALUE "], axis="CUSTOMER ID")], 
          axis=1)` Error Invalid Syntax

Comment: replace `df.PRODUCT FAMILY` with `df["PRODUCT FAMILY"]` @SIMON_py

Comment: `pd.concat([df, df["PRODUCT FAMILY"].str.get_dummies().multiply(df["NET SALES VALUE"], axis="CUSTOMER ID")], axis=1) `               `ValueError: No axis named CUSTOMER ID for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> `

Comment: @SIMON_py just `axis="index"` Not `axis="CUSTOMER ID"`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. In case of duplicate key, we usually aggregate values. Is that what you want ? Try this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='customer', columns='products', values ='Sales', aggfunc='sum')

products customer   a    b    c
   0         1    20.0  NaN  NaN
   1         2    NaN   20.0 NaN
   2         3    NaN   NaN 30.0
```

Comment: Hi Manish, If im using the aggfunc('sum') it will make the sum of customer ID 1 which i don't want. I want to keep all my rows

Comment: Yes, I realized that later. @jezrael answer seems correct.