# Look up weighting dataframe and apply to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, weighting

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
    Variable Name      Weight
     Variable1           2
     Variable2           .5
```

df2:

```
    Variable1      Variable2
        3              4 
        2              5
```

How can I multiply the weights by the numbers in each column to get the result:

df3:

```
    Variable1      Variable2
        6              2 
        4              2.5
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53217607/2336654 for more useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply a dataframe by a series or mapped index:

```
s = df1.set_index('Variable Name')['Weight']

df3 = df2 * s   # or df2.columns.map(s.get)

print(df3)

   Variable1  Variable2
0        6.0        2.0
1        4.0        2.5
```