# Dividing dataframe with another datafrmae with single row but same columns

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe df as:

```
                        Col1          Col2
Date                                      
2014-06-06              43.69         4.67
2014-06-09              45.47         4.70
2014-06-10              43.19         4.72
2014-06-11              47.58         4.64
```

I have another datafrmae `df2` as:

```
              Col1       Col2                 
0              2         .5
```

I want to divide `df` with `df2` to get the following:

[image]

But I am not sure how to perform this in a pythonic way?

Comment: `df1.div(df2.values)` or `df1.div(df2.to_numpy())` ?

Comment: It gives unable to coerce the shapes error.

Comment: either `df1.div(df2.iloc[0])` or `df1.div(df2.iloc[1], axis='rows')` would work.

Comment: This means you might have more rows and not just a single row. Check with @QuangHoang comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math between a dataframe and a series aligns the series index with the dataframe columns by default.   Soooo, get the first row of `df2` and you're set

```
df1 / df2.iloc[0]

              Col1  Col2
Date                    
2014-06-06  21.845  9.34
2014-06-09  22.735  9.40
2014-06-10  21.595  9.44
2014-06-11  23.790  9.28
```

---

If you want to alter the dataframe

```
df1 /= df2.iloc[0]

df1

Date                    
2014-06-06  21.845  9.34
2014-06-09  22.735  9.40
2014-06-10  21.595  9.44
2014-06-11  23.790  9.28
```

---

[SEE THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53217607/2336654)
For more information.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `numpy` will remove the index match

```
df1[:]=df1.values/df2.values
df1
              Col1  Col2
Date                    
2014-06-06  21.845  9.34
2014-06-09  22.735  9.40
2014-06-10  21.595  9.44
2014-06-11  23.790  9.28
```