# How to divide one dataframe by the other without converting to numpy first?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns, x and y, and a few hundred rows.
I have another dataframe with only one row and two columns, x and y.

I want to divide column x of the big dataframe by the value in x of the small dataframe, and column y by column y.

If I divide one dataframe by the other, I get all NaNs. For the division to work, I must convert the small dataframe to numpy.

Why can't I divide one dataframe by the other? What am I missing? I have a toy example below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
r = int(10)
df['x'] = np.arange(0,r)
df['y'] = df['x'] * 2

other_df = pd.DataFrame()
other_df['x'] = [100]
other_df['y'] = [400]

# This doesn't work - I get all nans
new = df / other_df

# this works - it gives me what I want
new2 = df / [100,400]

# this also works
new3 = df / other_df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Not an exact dup but this should be very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/53217607/2336654

Comment: Very useful, thanks! Is it fair to say that this is because numpy and pandas distinguish between a (1x2) array, which is considered two-dimensional, and a one-dimensional array with 2 elements?

Comment: Yes!  `[1, 2]` is different than `[[1, 2]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert one row `DataFrame` to `Series` for correct align `columns`, e.g. by selecting first row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
new = df / other_df.iloc[0]
print (new)
      x      y
0  0.00  0.000
1  0.01  0.005
2  0.02  0.010
3  0.03  0.015
4  0.04  0.020
5  0.05  0.025
6  0.06  0.030
7  0.07  0.035
8  0.08  0.040
9  0.09  0.045
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is that? Why does pandas not like dividing by a 1x2 dataframe but is fine dividing by a list, a numpy array or a series?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous - Because alignment - it means if want divide 2 DataFrames pandas try align index and columns values between both, and then divide. So here match ony first row, because here is intersection of first index values `0` in both DataFrames. Also columns names are same, so no problem.

Comment: If convert to Series there is only align between index of Series and columns names, here `x, y`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.divide()` to divide as `numpy` has a great property that is **Broadcasting**.

```
new = np.divide(df,other_df)
```

Please check this [link](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more details.