# Simple addition of different sizes DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, addition

I have 2 very simple addition problems with Pandas, I hope you could help me.

My first question:

Let say I have the following two dataframes: `a_df` and `b_df`

```
a = [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a)

a_df = 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0


b = [1,1,1,1]
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b).T

b_df=
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
```

I would like to add `b_df` to `a_df` to obtain `c_df` such that my expected output would be the follow:

```
c_df = 
   0  1  2  3
0  2  2  2  2
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  1  1
```

The current method I use is replicate `b_df` to the same size of `a_df` and carry out the addition, shown below. However, this method is not very efficient if my `a_df` is very very large.

```
a = [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a)

b = [1,1,1,1]
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b).T
b_df = pd.concat([b_df]*len(a_df)).reset_index(drop=True)

c_df = a_df + b_df
```

Are there any other ways to add `b_df`(without replicating it) to `a_df` in order to obtain what I want `c_df` to be?

My second question is very similar to my first one:

Let say I have `d_df` and `e_df` as follows:

```
d = [1,1,1,1]
d_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

d_df=
   0
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  1



e = [1]
e_df = pd.DataFrame(e)

e_df=
   0
0  1
```

I want to add `e_df` to `d_df` such that I would get the following result:

```
   0
0  2
1  2
2  2
3  2
```

Again, current I am replicating `e_df` using the following method (same as Question 1) before adding with `d_df`

```
d = [1,1,1,1]
d_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

e = [1]
e_df = pd.DataFrame(e)
e_df = pd.concat([e_df]*len(d_df)).reset_index(drop=True)

f_df = d_df + e_df
```

Is there a way without replicating `e_df`?

Please advise and help me. Thank you so much in advanced

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    pd.DataFrame(a_df.to_numpy() + b_df.to_numpy())


    0   1   2   3
0   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   1   1
```

numpy offers the broadcasting features that allows you to add the way u want, as long as the shape is similar on one end. I feel someone has answered something similar to this before. Once I find it I will reference it here. 
This article from [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) explains broadcasting pretty well

Answer (score 1):

For first convert one row `DataFrame` to `Series`:

```
c_df = a_df + b_df.iloc[0]
print (c_df)
   0  1  2  3
0  2  2  2  2
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  1  1
```

Same principe is for second:

```
c_df = d_df + e_df.iloc[0]
print (c_df)
   0
0  2
1  2
2  2
3  2
```

More information is possible find in [How do I operate on a DataFrame with a Series for every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217607/how-do-i-operate-on-a-dataframe-with-a-series-for-every-column).