# Pandas dataframe subtraction produces excess columns filled with NaN values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, each of them is (15, 1) shape.

When subtracting one from the other, the result is a (15, 15) shape dataframe. The first column gives the correct subtraction values, but the other fourteen columns are filled with NaN values.
(I get the same result using both traditional subtraction notation and .sub() )

Why is it introducing 14 additional columns? Shouldn't the result be a (15, 1) dataframe?

[image]

The dataframes are a concatenation of sections of another dataframe, hence the column/row labelling.

Comment: What is your code for subtract?

Comment: @jezrael Something along the lines of  ```df3 = df1.sub(df2)``` or  ```df3 = df1 - df2```

Comment: What is `print (df1.info())` and `print (df2.info())` ?

Comment: @jezrael Ah, that may have uncovered the issue. One of them was a true series, the other was a df with one column, 15 entries. Not realizing this, I was attempting to sub a df from a series. and switching the two (although values are negative) got ride of the unwanted columns filled with NaN values.I did not know about info()

Comment: ya, it was reason. Like in my sample `df1.sub(df2['B'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need subtract `Series` - selecting both columns:

```
np.random.seed(2020)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=15)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':np.random.randint(10, size=15)})

s = df1['A'].sub(df2['B'])
print (s)
0    -3
1     2
2    -2
3     6
4    -1
5    -5
6     1
7     4
8    -1
9    -1
10    3
11    0
12   -2
13    1
14   -4
dtype: int32
```

Or select second one with `axis=0` in [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
s = df1.sub(df2['B'], axis=0)
print (s)
    A
0  -3
1   2
2  -2
3   6
4  -1
5  -5
6   1
7   4
8  -1
9  -1
10  3
11  0
12 -2
13  1
14 -4
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas. Does specifically naming the column B to subtract from A yield a different result than subtracting the entirety of df2 from df1?

Comment: @tcolbert - I think it is more complidated like seems, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217607/how-do-i-operate-on-a-dataframe-with-a-series-for-every-column) for more info.