# Multiply dataframes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need help to process the following operation : I would like to create a new df by multiplying the value in key_3 (int) in df1 by the % in df2 so that I will get 4 columns instead of 1 with an allocation based on % df2.

df1
key key_2   key_3
aaa bbb value int

df2
key key_2   key_3   e1  e2  e3  e4
aaa bbb str value   %   %   %   %

Thank you for your help !

Comment: [Do not post your data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Can create a dataframe construction with mock data and expected output?

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702760/how-to-multiply-multiple-columns-by-a-column-in-pandas); use `df3 = df2.multiply(df1.key_3, axis="index")`

Comment: it's not same because in my case I have key_3 in df1 which contains an integer I would like to multiply this value by e1,e2, etc. knowing that the value of key_3 in my df2 is the name of the columns in df1