# Pandas - Weighted sum of columns, where weights are columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'state1' : [1, 2, 3], 'state2' : [2, 4, 6], 'pop1' : [1, 1, 1], 'pop2' : [1, 1, 2]})
```

And I want to produce a sumproduct across columns, something like this:

```
      state1  state2  pop1  pop2 sumproduct
0       1       2     1     1    3
1       2       4     1     1    6
2       3       6     1     2    15
```

The following has failed:

```
(df_data[['state1', 'state2']] * df_data[['pop1', 'pop2']]).sum(axis = 1)
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
dtype: float64
```

How do I just do a sumproduct on these to get a new column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Elementwise multiplication of two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022865/pandas-elementwise-multiplication-of-two-dataframes)

Comment: e.g. `df_data['sumproduct'] = df_data[['state1', 'state2']].mul(df_data[['pop1', 'pop2']].values).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Using values is however risky, this only works if the columns are in a correct order.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen, please make an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

@BigBen has the right answer. I just provide a slight variation in case you have additional such columns.

```
# Calculate the 'sumproduct' column for all state-pop pairs
state_cols = [col for col in df_data.columns if col.startswith('state')]
pop_cols = [col for col in df_data.columns if col.startswith('pop')]

df_data['sumproduct'] = df_data[state_cols].mul(df_data[pop_cols].values).sum(axis=1)

print(df_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, please let me know if it works or you need further assistance:

```
# Perform element-wise multiplication and sum across each row
df_data['sumproduct'] = (df_data[['state1', 'state2']].values * df_data[['pop1', 'pop2']].values).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach (independent of the number of pairs) would be to first reshape the DataFrame with [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), then multiply `state * pop` (e.g. with [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)) and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
df_data['sumproduct'] = (pd
   .wide_to_long(df_data.reset_index(), stubnames=['state', 'pop'],
                 i='index', j='n')
   .eval('state * pop')
   .groupby('index').sum()
)
```

Output:

```
   state1  state2  pop1  pop2  sumproduct
0       1       2     1     1           3
1       2       4     1     1           6
2       3       6     1     2          15
```

Intermediate after `wide_to_long`:

```
         state  pop
index n            
0     1      1    1
1     1      2    1
2     1      3    1
0     2      2    1
1     2      4    1
2     2      6    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if there are few columns, then use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)?

```
df_data['sumproduct'] = df_data.eval("""state1 * pop1 + state2 * pop2""")
```